# Real Time calculation JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to perform realtime calculation, but it doesn't work for me. I'm avoiding using id selector to apply the same code over multiple forms

```js
function OgKeyPress() {
  var amount = $(this);
  var s = amount.value;
  var tax = $(this).closest("table").find("tr td div").first().find("p input");
  var total = $(this).closest("table").find("tr td div").last().find("p input");

  var t = tax.value = (1 / 10).toFixed(1);
  total.value = Number(s) + Number(t);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <div>
      <input type="text" onKeyPress="OgKeyPress()" onKeyUp="OgKeyPress()" name="amount">
    </div>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <b>tax</b>
          <p>
            <input name="tax" type="text" readonly="readonly">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>total</b>
          <p>
            <input name="sum" type="text" readonly="readonly">
          </p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here. Firstly the main problem is because your HTML is invalid; you cannot place a `div` as the child of a `table`. It needs to be within a `tr` and `td` or `th`. This is why `closest()` isn't working, as the renderer is moving the `div` *outside* of the table to make the HTML valid.

You also state that you don't want to use `id` attributes as this HTLM structure is repeated, which is fine, use `class` attributes instead. Then you can group the same functionality for all those elements without having to duplicate your JS.

You should also not be using `on*` inline event handlers. Aside from being massively outdated, they do not retain scope of the element which raised the element, so the `this` reference will most likely be the `window`, causing problems with your calculation logic. To fix this use unobtrusive event handlers, such as jQuery's `on()` and the `input` event, which also covers pasting in content with the mouse.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.amount').on('input', function() {
    var $amount = $(this);
    var $table = $amount.closest('table');
    var $tax = $table.find(".tax");
    var $total = $table.find(".total");

    var tax = parseFloat((1 / 10).toFixed(1));
    $tax.val(tax);
    $total.val(parseFloat($amount.val()) + tax);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="amount" class="amount">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <b>tax</b>
          <p>
            <input name="tax" type="text" class="tax" readonly="readonly">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>total</b>
          <p>
            <input name="sum" type="text" class="total" readonly="readonly">
          </p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

One final note, the `tax` calculation is hard-coded to `0.1`, so the logic seems a little over-complicated when you could just add `0.1` to the user's input. I'm going to assume this is a work in progress, though, and that the tax rate is variable.

Comment: thx alot for the help. you are right tax is variable based on amount. How can I set if statement based on amount valuable different tax calculation should be performed. I update my code above. with if statement but it only works for cretin numbers

Comment: I can't see any update to the code above? I'd suggest starting a new question for any further issues you have, anyway.

Comment: here u go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114478/real-time-calculation-jquery-with-if-statment