# Real Time calculation JQuery with IF statment

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to perform realtime calculation, but it doesn't work for me. I'm avoiding using id selector to apply the same code over multiple forms. Below if the code with if statement which works correctly for some numbers only.

```js
$(function() {
 $('.amount').on('input', function() {
  var $amount = $(this);
  var $form = $amount.closest('form');
  var $tax = $form.find(".tax");
  var $sum = $form.find(".sum");
  var s = $amount.val();
if ( s < 100  ) {
   var tax = parseFloat((1 / 10).toFixed(1));
} else if ( s >= 100 && s <= 1000) {
    var tax = Number(s) * (0.5/100);
    var tax = tax.toFixed(1);
} else {
        var tax = tax.value = (10);
}
$tax.val(tax);
$sum.val(parseFloat(Number(s)) + Number(tax));
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <input type="text" name="amount" class="amount">
        <div>
          <b>tax</b>
          <p>
            <input name="tax" type="text" class="tax" readonly="readonly">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>total</b>
          <p>
            <input name="sum" type="text" class="sum" readonly="readonly">
          </p>
</form>
```

Comment: You mention it works correctly for some numbers. What are some of the exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the `else` condition, where the amount is `> 1000`. You're working with the `tax` value when it hasn't been defined, hence you get an error on this line:

```
var tax = tax.value = (10);
```

`tax` is also an integer (or string as you call `toFixed()` on it) which will never have a `value` property.

To fix this, define the `tax` variable first, then amend it in all `if` conditions:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.amount').on('input', function() {
    var $amount = $(this);
    var amount = $amount.val()
    var $form = $amount.closest('form');
    var $tax = $form.find(".tax");
    var tax = 0;
    var $sum = $form.find(".sum");
    
    if (amount < 100) {
      tax = (1 / 10).toFixed(1);
    } else if (amount <= 1000) {
      tax = (Number(amount) * (0.5 / 100)).toFixed(1);
    } else {
      tax = 10;
    }
    
    $tax.val(tax);
    $sum.val(parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat(tax));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="amount" class="amount">
  <div>
    <b>tax</b>
    <p>
      <input name="tax" type="text" class="tax" readonly="readonly">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>total</b>
    <p>
      <input name="sum" type="text" class="sum" readonly="readonly">
    </p>
</form>
```

Also note that the `>= 100` check isn't needed in the `else` if, and I changed `s` to `amount`. Always use meaningful variable names.